# Not able to display image

Tags: java, mysql

I am creating web application where I am storing image in MYSQL DB as MEDIUMBLOB and displaying them on the browser.

```
PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT pdfImage FROM pdfInfo WHERE pdfinfoid=?");
psmt.setString(1, what);
ResultSet rs1 = psmt.executeQuery();

while (rs1.next()) {
    System.out.println("inside rs1.mext");
    String imgLen = rs1.getString(1);
    System.out.println(imgLen.length());
    int len = imgLen.length();
    System.out.println("length inside == " + len);
    byte[] rb = new byte[len];
    InputStream readImg = rs1.getBinaryStream(1);
    InputStream inputStream = readImg;
    int index = readImg.read(rb, 0, len);
    System.out.println("index----------------" + index);
    response.reset();
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(len));
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=/file.png");
    response.setContentType("image/png");
    response.getOutputStream().write(rb, 0, len);
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
}
```

The problem is that I am able to see images locally and when I take project live. The problem is with one image only.

Output for the sout statements are as below.

```
INFO: inside rs1.mext
INFO: 5942414
INFO: length inside == 5942414
INFO: index----------------5942414
INFO: leng here is 5942414
```

When this info is on **localhost, I can view the image**, however when **I take this project online, I am not able to view the image**.

Do I need to set any parameter anywhere so that I can see the image.

Other sout statements are as below for which I can see images.

```
INFO: inside rs1.mext
INFO: 204999
INFO: length inside == 204999
INFO: index----------------204999
INFO: leng here is 204999



INFO: inside rs1.mext
INFO: 515274
INFO: length inside == 515274
INFO: index----------------515274
INFO: leng here is 515274
```

Comment: store the path to the image rather than the image in the database and things will go smoother

Comment: @Ibu : I know this was best solution, however the problem is I have done 80% of the coding and making BLOB to path is tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be the line:

```
int index = readImg.read(rb, 0, len);
```

The `read` method is not guaranteed to read all the data you are requesting.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)

"Reads up to len bytes of data from the input stream into an array of bytes. An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller number may be read. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer."

Comment: as you see, "length inside == " & "index -------" number are same, means all data is readed...